# application of Hahn-Banach to space of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Consider the set $BC([0,\infty))$ of bounded continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ with supremum norm.
I have shown that there exists a bounded linear functional $F$ on this space such that $F(f)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ if the limit exists and $F(f) \leq \limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ for all $f \in BC([0,\infty))$.

 I have the following question: Is it necessarily true that $F(f) \geq \liminf_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ for all $f \in BC([0,\infty))$?

 If not, can we find a counterexample?

Comment: It is true!  Use that $F(f)=-F(-f)$